# iOS Extract all frames from a video

Tags: ios, objective-c, video

I have to extract all frames from video file and then save them to file.
I tried to use `AVAssetImageGenerator`, but it's very slow - it takes 1s - 3s per each frame ( sample 1280x720 MPEG4 video ) without saving to file process.

Is there anyway to make it much faster?
OpenGL, GPU, (...)?

I will be very grateful for showing me right direction.

Comment: if you are going to do this on a ios device, I'm sure it consumes more resources. Start with gif files and try to convert it into individual frames,then go for higher format.

Answer (score 3):

`AVAssetImageGenerator` is a random access (seeking) interface, and seeking takes time, so one optimisation could be to use an `AVAssetReader` which will quickly and sequentially vend you frames. You can also choose to work in yuv format, which will give you smaller frames (and I think) faster decoding.

However, those raw frames are enormous: are 1280px * 720px * 4 bytes/pixel (if in RGBA), which is about 3.6MB each. You're going to need some pretty serious compression if you want to keep them all (MPEG4 @ 720p comes to mind :).

So what are you trying to achieve?

Are you sure you want fill up your users' disks at a rate of 108MB/s (at 30fps) or 864MB/s (at 240fps)?

Comment: So in basic scenario I want to save the video but after removing SOME of frames from original one (without any filters, single frame editing  etc. ) .

Comment: Ok, in that case you should be reading the frames via an `AVAssetReader` and conditionally writing some of those frames out to another with an `AVAssetWriter`.